# is there a way to make the window scroll when the mouse gets near it's boundaries using mootools?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, uiscrollview, mootools, scroll

i need to make a drag and drop list for re-ordering which is longer than the screen height.

in order to make this usable, the window needs to scroll while the element selected and the mouse is near the boundaries of the screen.

what is the best way to achieve this?

thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://mootools.net/docs/more/Interface/Scroller